# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting range compared to cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Attempting to compare cells in range G3:AM46 to their row's corresponding E cell, and when the number in the range cells is less than or equal to the E cell it should highlight it. None of these fields have any formulas or conditional formatting other than this, they are all basic numerical values.

The goal in plainer English is for me to be able to put in the number of each item that I have in col E, and in G-AM put how many I need to be able to build the structure it's the column for. I want it to highlight the ones that I have enough of that item to build that part of the structure.

Attempts that have failed:

- Range: G3:AM3 (or G3:AM46), Format Cells if: "less than or equal to" $E3

  - Result: All highlighted regardless of higher or lower
- Range: G3:AM3 (or G3:AM46), Format cells if: "greater than or equal to" $E3

  - Result: No cells highlighted regardless of higher or lower
- Range: G3:AM46, Format cells if: "Custom Formula" =$G3:$AM46>$E3:$E46 or =$G3:$AM46=$E3:$E46 or =$G3:$AM46<=$E3:$E46

  - Result: Same as above two (depending on greater/less than)

I've also tried a wide variety of combinations related to the $ but I may have missed some. I've also tried just doing it by column (compare G to E without ranges) and I can't get that to work. I tried a single cell and that didn't work either.

Spreadsheet is located here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NI-eDdxBMKQzNR-LdRKX2zJ-d1uUllImPTzeOdQI8lI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to be any clearer than cell A gets highlighted if cell B has a value equal or higher than it, but I want to be able to apply it to a range so I don't have to apply conditional formatting to 1452 cells individually

Answer (score 1):

Partially solved

I sorted out how to get it to work on a column at a time

```
Range: G3:G

Format cells if: "Custom Formula" =G3<$E3
```

this seems to work, I'm too exhausted to attempt to expand it into a multi-column fix, I don't look forward to doing this 33 times but I will if I have to.

Comment: Just apply it to `G3:AM`. Formula will be the same `=G3<$E3`